# How to display pre-determined path on the map?

Tags: java, android, dictionary, offline, osmdroid

I am using osmdroid library and I am not familiar with all of its features. Basically, I have an offline map displayed using mapnik mapsource. My project right now enables the user to locate his current location and choose his desired destination. What I need to do next is to draw a line / path following the main roads in the map from the users current location to his destination.

Is there any relation with pathoverlay in osmdroid? Your knowledge and information is a great help for me. Thank you, and have a great day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may help you,

http://www.androidadb.com/source/osmdroid-read-only/osmdroid-android/src/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/PathOverlay.java.html